# How to show before and after images of moving parts on a model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, workflow, keyframes

I am a bit of newbie to Blender and I am not sure if I am wording this question right, Anyway I have a project ( A Mech) where I want to show stuff like the images in this link.

https://www.artstation.com/artwork/2VnPB

anyway, I was wondering how to go about doing this with out having to rig a bunch of parts which I think would be a waste of time since I am not actually animating this stuff.   I just want to depict/show the before and after images of how stuff moves/transforms. I even tried contacting the artist in the link a while back but no replies, but I hope this makes sense and any help or resources out there is appreciated .

Comment: Hi :). Could you please pick one of the images and add it to the question directly? Not everyone will be clicking through links. Cheers :))

Comment: You can duplicate the model and modify it in Edit mode.